# How could be notified once USB device is attached/detached in linux system and read the file from USB

Tags: linux, usb, libusb, udev

I need to be notified once new USB device is attached/detached in Linux system.

And once new device will be attached I need to read the config file("config/conf.xml") and notify to REST API.

I looked into [libusb](https://github.com/larskanis/libusb) and [udev-rules](http://hackaday.com/2009/09/18/how-to-write-udev-rules/) but not sure what is the best way to achieve this.

Please give your view/suggestion on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd add udev rule first with running your custom script. Something like:

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd?1", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", RUN+="/path/to/your/script %k"
```

`%k` is kernel parameter that is passed to your script.

**From udev man:**

```
$kernel, %k
    The kernel name for this device.
```

In the script I'd use `curl`. If you don't need some tricky logic. If so, I'd use python.

Anyway I think udev is perfect for this problem.

Comment: Fixed my answer. You can use %k to pass **kernel argument** to your script. In my tests was passed sdc1.

Comment: thanks, I have mounted the device and then read the specific file and umont it.